# Plumbing with 2 valve going into the concrete basement floor?

Tags: plumbing, basement, valve

[image]

We are about to buy a house & we saw this during the inspection. The inspector couldn't confirm what it was for & neither the current homeowner.

So basically on the left, we have the main which is coming from the floor & going through the counter then it's looping back to what is seen in the picture. Both of the pipe pointed by the red arrows goes into the floor, one has obviously been cut & abandoned but the other one is connected to that O with 2 valves. With the limited info I have on these, does anyone have a clue as to what this could be or have been used for & why there are 2 valves going to that pipe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may have at one time been plumbed for a water softener. Such a setup often has sets of valves that allow for switching between normal operation and back flush operation.

Comment: I was thinking this as well but based on the picture I am confused as to how a water softener introduces the softened water back into the supply line. Additionally, I would expect a valve on the northern horizontal pipe to allow for maintenance.

Comment: Yeah, there should be a 3rd valve on the horizontal section if this was for a softener. Normal operation is the (missing) 3rd valve is closed, the 2 existing valves opened. For maintenance, close the two valves that are here and open the (missing) 3rd valve to keep water flowing to the house.